# How to implement log4j in IBM BPM?

Tags: log4j, business-process-management, ibm-bpm, log4javascript, ibm-baw

If you had to implement log4j logging in IBM BPM application from scratch, what will be the step by step process with detailed explanation for a beginner level?

I know about what is the code for writing logging code but don't have any clue about how the implementation begins from scratch.
var logMessage;
logMessage =  'Testing logging ';
Packages.org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configure(tw.env.path+"xyzlog4j.xml");
var logger = Packages.org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(tw.env.logpath);
logger.info(logMessage);

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.